# Convert PyTorch GPU tensor to Tensorflow 1.x tensor without leaving the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow1.15

I have PyTorch tensors in the GPU, which I would like to convert to Tensorflow 1.x tensors without ever leaving the GPU.

I don't care about passing gradients back and forth. I just want the tensor to stay in the GPU. I don't care if my PyTorch tensor is copied to a TF tensor or modified in place.

I am aware that I can [convert to numpy on the CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722008/is-there-any-way-to-convert-pytorch-tensor-to-tensorflow-tensor/60724300#60724300) and reload onto the GPU. However, I must stay on GPU for speed.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics#device_names), might be what you need?

Comment: @M.Innat Unfortunately, I don't think it has the information I need, and if it did it would be tf=>pytorch, not the other way around.